# PyQt5: How do I "collect" or "receive" an emitted signal?

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots

In my code, I have 2 classes in 2 separate files. I have a signal `testSignal`, a button `pushButton` and I connected the button like this:

```py
testSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

pushButton.pressed.connect(buttonPressed)

def buttonPressed(self):
    testSignal.emit()
```

Now what I want to do is "receive" the emitted signal in the class/file, but I'm somewhat in the dark on how emit() actually works. Does anyone have any links for guides for the emit() function or can help somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. First of all, a signal should be declared at the *class* level, so that the signal of the *instance* can be correctly connected. The `emit()` of a signal *emits* that signal and calls all slots/functions connected to it, possibly with the provided arguments (or none, like in your case). That said, it's not clear what you actually need/want to do: can you explain yourself better?

Comment: Ok, so when I emit a signal all connected functions to that signal are being called, right? So how do I connect functions to a signal?

Comment: The syntax is `signal.connect(function)`. If the signal is in the current class, then `self.testSignal.connect(self.someFunction)`.

Comment: So in my example it would be ```testSignal.connect(function)``` right?
Because when I do it in my code I get : ```AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect'```

Comment: As explained before, signals *must* be declared at the *class* level in the `class ClassName():` constructor indentation level.

Comment: Hm oke... Still struggling here a bit. In general I have a model-view-presenter construct and I want that when i click a button, the presenter gets notified and reacts to it.

Comment: The fact that you're using such a paradygm doesn't change anything, a signal has to be created in the class declaration, not when the instance already is created, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: In my code it's like this: ```class Classname: (newline) testSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()```

Comment: I think I got it now. Sorry for being such a nuisance ^^` But you actually helped a lot ^^

Comment: No. You can only use Qt signals in QObject subclasses (or QWidget subclasses, as they inherit from QObject). You *cannot* use signals from standard python object classes.

Comment: I know, but I didnt say that. My bad, sorry. My class inherits from QtWidgets. Sorry

Comment: I got one more question underneath your solution, if you dont mind :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Py]Qt signals **must** be declared at the class level, as they become "active" only whenever a new class instance is created. Also, they can only be used for classes that inherit from QObject (including QWidget subclasses), and using them with standard python `object` classes will **not** work.

```
class SomeWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    testSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...
        pushButton.pressed.connect(self.buttonPressed)
        # connect the custom signal with an *instance method*
        self.testSignal.connect(self.someInstanceFunction)

    def buttonPressed(self):
        # emit the signal
        self.testSignal.emit()

    def someInstanceFunction(self):
        print('hello from the instance!')


def someAnonymousFunction():
    print('hello from outside!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = SomeWindow()
    # connect the signal with an anonymous function
    window.testSignal.connect(someAnonymousFunction)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Obviously the example above doesn't make a lot of sense, as custom signals are normally used to communicate between instances of (possibly different) classes, but that's just for explanation purposes. Also, you could "concatenate" signals (as long as their signature is compatible):

```
class SomeWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    testSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...
        # emit the testSignal when the button emits its pressed signal
        pushButton.pressed.connect(self.testSignal)
        self.testSignal.connect(self.someInstanceFunction)

    # ...
```

Note that if you want to do something when the user *clicks* a button, you should use [`clicked()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked), not the `pressed()` one and the difference is *very* important: it's common convention that a button is considered clicked only when the user presses **and** releases the mouse button while still in the button area, so that the "click" can be avoided if the mouse button is released *outside* it. If you connect to `pressed()`, the signal will be emitted as soon as the mouse button is just *pressed down* on the button, which is not considered a standard behavior.

Comment: Thanks mate. You really helped me out a lot. I highly appreciate it. And also thanks for the side note about ```clicked()``` and ```pressed()```. Much appreciated

Comment: I've got but one more question, if you dont mind. Since I can emit values with the signals I want to emit a slider value with the signal and use it in a function connected to the signal. How do I do that?

Comment: Can't you just connect to the existing slider's `valueChanged` signal?

Comment: Oh, fair point. I might try that yeah. Thank you very much mate for all your effort